# div content overflowing outside of another div

Tags: html, css

Before, all **[this](http://www.habeshajobs.com/liip.php)** is my page, and I was in the middle of creating a layout, using css `@media` query, for detecting and adjusting the page, depending on the pixel of the browser....

All was going fine, but if you see:

```
<div id='x'>
    <h1>I am content </h1>
    <h1>I am content </h1>
    <h1>I am content </h1>
    <h1>I am content </h1>
    <h1>I am content </h1>
    <h1>I am content </h1>
    <h1>I am content </h1>
</div>
```

You will notice, it has overflown of the parent `div` which is `<div id='sep'></div>` ONLY, when viewed from desktop.

You can check the source code of the page, or here is the full code:

```
<html>
<head><style>
body{margin:0px; padding:0px;}
#a{height:150px; background-color:#ffffff; border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;}
#x{min-height:350px; margin-top: 10px; background-color:#CCC;}
#y{min-height:30px; margin-top: 10px; background-color:#CCC;}

@media all and (min-width:700px){

#b{width:100%;  min-height:400px;}
    #sep{width:960px; margin:auto;}
    #x{width:65%; float:left;}
    #y{width:32%; float:right; }
#c{background-color:#656565; height:80px;}
.for-mob{display:none;}
.for-desc{background-color:green;}
}
@media all and (max-width:700px){
.for-mob{background-color:green;}
.for-desc{display:none;}
#b{width:100%; min-height:400px; }
#x{width:100%; display:block; }
#y{width:100%; display:block; }
#c{background-color:#656565; height:100px;}

}
</style></head>


<body>

<div id='a'> <h1>I am header </h1>
</div> 

<div id='b'>
<div id='sep'>

    <div id='x'>
    <h1>I am content </h1>
    <h1>I am content </h1>
    <h1>I am content </h1>
    <h1>I am content </h1>
    <h1>I am content </h1>
    <h1>I am content </h1>
    <h1>I am content </h1>
    </div>
    <div id='y'>
    <h1>I am sidebar </h1>
    </div>
</div> 
</div> 
<div class='for-desc'><h1>If you shrink the browser, I become invisible</h1> </div>
<div class='for-mob'><h1>If you maximize the browser, I become invisible</h1></div>

<div id='c'>
<h1> I am a simple footer </h1>
</div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've not specified any height for `#sep`, it implies that you want it to expand with content. You can add `overflow: hidden` to it to make it expand

```
#sep {
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 960px;
}
```

State your requirement in the question if this answer doesn't *answer* your question :)

Comment: but `width: 960px;` defeats the purpose, of making it mobile friendly.

Comment: @kranzdot - the width is something you posted, Ejay didn't just make it up.

Comment: `but width: 960px; defeats the purpose, of making it mobile friendly.` _You said it man! nobody sets fixed width in responsive_. saying _nobody_ is exaggeration :D

Comment: @j08691 I set it for desktop, but in mobile width it is overidden.

Comment: @Ejay I don't get it, but the other user's response fixed my problem

Comment: @kranzdot - the point here is that `overflow:auto` or `overflow:hidden` on your `#sep` div fixes the problem. IMO it's a better solution than the old clearfix hack.

Comment: Wow, I had used @Ejay's code outside, the media query, but now I used it inside it works, But, I need your opinions, I am about to create a long project website, and if my code is good enough to start working with it?

Comment: @kranzdot good for you :) but I don't see that solution removing the fixed width. Actually you've got it mixed up (for us). `You will notice, it has overflown of the parent div which is <div id='sep'></div> ONLY, when viewed from desktop.` implies to me that you want to fix it for desktop only. `but width: 960px; defeats the purpose, of making it mobile friendly` means you expect the CSS to affect mobile but then `I set it for desktop, but in mobile width it is overidden` says fixed width doesn't affect the mobile. Then what is your initial `...defeats the purpose....` objection about?

Comment: Well, I placed the `#spe` outside, the the `@media` query, and then, when I resized the browser to a mobile level, there was horizontal bar at the footer to fill the `960` width, but when I moved the `#sep` to inside of the `@media` query of the desktop, it works fine. 

Thank you, but I need to know if this script is good enough to serve as a platform/framework, for future website, I will design to make them mobile/desktop friendly

Answer (score 0):

Apply a clearfix to the non-floated div that contains the floated divs (either `#b` or `#sep`).

```
#sep:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}
```

Gleaned from http://www.css-101.org/articles/clearfix/latest-new-clearfix-so-far.php

Comment: Super. it did it. I have never even seen/read of anything you have written. Anyway, I made the script from scratch, for obvious comparability reasons, and honestly, I need your opinion, if my code is just fine, or mediocre before, I build a website based on it